# C fwrite() not writing array properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to write first 40 elements of fibonacci sequence into a fibonacci.txt file using fwrite() but it's writing random symbols.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 40

int main(void) {
    FILE *izlaz = fopen("fibonacci.txt", "w");
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    int niz[40] = {1, 1};
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX-2; i++) {
      int pom = b;
      b = a + b;
      a = pom;
      niz[i + 2] = b;
    }
    fwrite(niz, sizeof(niz), 1, izlaz);
    fclose(izlaz);
    return 0;
}
```

[fibonacci.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWPLr.png)

Comment: You are writing binary values not text values. If you want text you need to convert the values to ascii before writing to file with something like `fprintf` or `snprintf`.

Comment: Furthermore, if you do want to write the binary image of the array, better open that file with `"wb"`, unless you only care about the program working on Unix.